# Vue Components not showing/updating

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am working in Laravel 5.4, and Vue components are not showing/updating.
I start a new project and create a route /chat in web.php

This is chat.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
<example></example>
<chat></chat>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.Laravel = { csrfToken: '{{ csrf_token() }}' };
</script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));
Vue.component('chat', require('./components/Chat.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
el: '#app'
});
```

Example and Chat components are some basic templates, I am not passing any data, just plain text.

Chat.vue

```
<template lang="html">
<div id="content">
    <h1>Messages</h1>
    <p>Message text</p>
    <small>Hiii</small>
</div>
 </template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>
```

When I run php artisan for the first time, everything works. I try to edit some text in Chat.vue, like change 'Hiiii' to Hello, when I reload the page it won't change, it just stays the same. I tried restarting the pc, running php artisan again, anything I could think of.
I tried putting some Vue code directly in chat.blade.php, and than it works. It looks like it is not detecting changes in app.js and components.
FYI, I even deleted the Example.vue component. It still appeared on the page.

Comment: I don't know what Laravel do under hood and how it compiles stuff, but I think that php artisan doesn't take care of Javascript.
Have you tried to run `npm run dev` after the editing file ?

Comment: You could also use `npm run watch` so that file should be recompiled on change and it will save on the initial overhead on all subsequent requests.

Comment: It works now, thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to solve this problem is to update npm because it will update all the packages and install missing packages, as a result you will have laravel mix compiling your assets; right now you are not able to do so.

```
npm update
```

For some people an easier solution can work which is to run the *watch-pol* command

```
npm run watch-poll
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to clear browser cache? This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was deleting the browser history every day to see changes made in the editor so I searched for a solution.

All you need to do is:

1. Go to developer tools.
2. Click on the Network tab
3. Click disable cache (Look at the highlighted portion in the image below)
4. Refresh your page again!

[image: dev tools screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

Sometime copying code from internet we add some unwanted line.
Just check this line from App/Config/app .
Make sure it is in Development mode.

```
'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'development'),
```

Answer (score -6):

copy this code in app.blade.php :

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app'
});
```

Comment: This doesn't explain how or why it will work, please add more information regarding the solution.

Comment: Please explain your solutions instead of writing the code.

Comment: The code is already in the app.js, then why he needs to add it in blade file..!